# How to enable XP Visual Style to winForm controls

Tags: c#

Is there anyway possible to enable my winForm to display itself with xp visual style even the OS has visual style disable?

Comment: no. nope. nada. not gonna happen.

Comment: But it doesn't hurt to ask ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Not with the help of the OS. You would need to use custom made controls that can provide (emulated) the styles independently (or write the custom controls your self emulating the styles).